# Error installing VS 2013 Community on win 7

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I am trying to install VS 2013 on a windows 7 pro machine, but I get an error message that says I need a newer version of windows, which is not true.[image]

Comment: *"Newer version of Windows"* may refer to required Updates, not a different version than Win7. Check Windows Updates.

Comment: yes I did but i can't update it either i get another error sayins that I need to start the service, I start it on cmd by issuing the commant net start wuauserv, and still can't update.

Comment: I guess it's a windows updater problem than.